# Comparing chars in C++ - argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *

Tags: c++, structured-programming

Im trying to compare 2 values in C++ (which im new to so please go easy)

```
struct styles{
int itemNo;
char desc[26]; 
char brand[21]; //between 3 - 20
char category;
double cost;
};
```

struct declared above, then im using this code in another function

```
char cat[2];
for (x=0;x<size;x++)
{

    if (strcmp(cat,styleAr[x].category)==0)
```

its giving me an error with the 'styleAr[x].category' in the if statement:
**argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char ***

any explanations on how I could solve this would be great

Comment: Go a lot easier on yourself and use `std::string`.

Comment: size declared as size = createArray(hd1, styleAr); and i pass this through in the function call

Comment: @chris: Better still, use `char` to represent a single character (which is what `cat` looks like it wants to be).

Comment: @MikeSeymour, True for those, but `desc` and `brand` should really be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `cat` is a string (that is, one character followed by a `'\0'`), then you should do this:

```
if (cat[0] == styleAr[x].category)
```

But of course, if you use `std::string cat` and `std::string category`, you can just write:

```
if (cat == styleAr[x].category)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have `category` as a single `char` and `cat` is an array of chars (i.e. a `char *`)... you probably didn't mean to compare a string with a single character

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` compares character arrays, but category is just a single `char`, hence the error. You can compare two chars directly using `==`
If category is supposed to be a single char, you need to change the comparison code

```
char cat='?';//or whatever you are looking for

for (x=0;x<size;x++)
{
    if (cat == styleAr[x].category)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a two-char array (`cat`), that is NOT initalized to any value (at least not in the code that you showed us), to a single char.

The `strcmp` function accepts two arguments of type `const char*`, that is two null-terminated c-style strings (a char array whose last element is a '\0' character, the null character).

If you want to compare just one character, use the following code:

```
char cat = ; // Put the character you want to compare styleAr[x].category against there.

for (int x = 0 ; x < size; x++)
{
    if (cat == styleAr[x].category)
    {
       // The two characters are equal.
    }
}
```